# Split multiple delimited string into unique rows - basically return unique words of sentences from table

Tags: regex, oracle, plsql, oracle11g, plsqldeveloper

Lot of different post out there on this subject.
But I really can't find the one suitable for my project.
I have a table with 4 columns of varchar2, length 20,60,72 and 160. Containing apx ≈ 700 000 records with data of items/products.

Example of table:

```
Text                    Id  SHNAM
LEVI,GRADY Whitley      1   007C
Levi Grady;Whitley      2   0001
BEVIS,GRADY Leblanc     3   007D
Aladdin Grady;Green     4   0002
ULLA,GRADY Holman       5   0003
```

From this table I would like to populate a new table or a materialized view of every unique word. Delimiters used are either space, comma or semicolon (', ;').

Expected output:

```
OUTPUT
Levi
GRADY
Whitley
BEVIS
Leblanc
Aladdin
Green
ULLA
Holman
```

Note that the check is not case sensitive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

E.g. this blog post applies to your question: [Splitting a comma delimited string the RegExp way, Part Two](http://nuijten.blogspot.fi/2011/08/splitting-comma-delimited-string-regexp.html). My answer is derived directly the blog:

```
with data_(id_, str) as (
  select 1, 'LEVI,GRADY Whitley' from dual union all
  select 2, 'Levi Grady;Whitley' from dual union all
  select 3, 'BEVIS,GRADY Leblanc' from dual union all
  select 4, 'aladdin grady;green' from dual union all
  select 5, 'ULLA,GRADY Holman' from dual union all
  select 6, '1aar,1bar;1car 1dar,1ear' from dual
)
select distinct lower(regexp_substr(str, '[^,;[:space:]]+', 1, rownum_)) as splitted
  from data_
 cross join (select rownum as rownum_
               from (select max(regexp_count(str, '[,;[:space:]]')) + 1 as max_
                       from data_
                    )
            connect by level <= max_
            )
 where regexp_substr(str, '[^,;[:space:]]+', 1, rownum_) is not null
 order by splitted
;
```

Note that this query doesn't have exactly the same output that you have listed in the question for the ids from 1 to 5. You expected Levi (with initcap) and GRADY (all caps) even the both names has both variations - this is inconsistent so I simply ignored it.